# knex (postgres) referencing a column (not unique) in another table

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

`table_a` has a regular column called `item_id` with `int` type and it currently is not indexed. 
`table_b` has a column called `item_id` that i want to have reference the `item_id` in `table_a`

All of this would be normally fine, however, the `table_a.item_id` cannot be setup with a unique index constraint because there are rows that contain the same values.

How can `table_b.item_id` create a foreign key mapping to reference `table_a.item_id` when I'm unable to set `table_a.item_id` with unique?

How do I setup a non-unique based index so I can map the relationship?

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to mark item_id in table_a as a unique in order to make it a foreign key.

```js
await knex.schema.createTable('table_b', (t) => {
  t.integer('item_id').unsigned().notNullable();

  t.foreign('item_id')
   .references(`table_a.item_id`)
   .onDelete('cascade')
   .onUpdate('cascade');
});
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I tried what you suggested, but it still will not work. The migration always fails with the same response:


"there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table"

Comment: this is weird, try to add other column which will be the index

Comment: yes i hear you. let me review the schema. I appreciate your prompt response 